# How to delete a Collection Type?

Tags: strapi

I created a collection type in the Strapi admin panel and now I want to delete it, but I don't see an option anywhere in the admin panel to do so. I must be missing something obvious, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it in Content Type Builder, steps:

1. Enter Admin panel
2. Content Type Builder
3. Click a collection type
4. Edit (small pen icon next to the name)
5. Delete
6. Confirm

[Official docs - Deleting content-types](https://docs.strapi.io/user-docs/latest/content-types-builder/managing-content-types.html#deleting-content-types)

---

Another way is to use the admin API, make a `DELETE` call to:

```
/content-type-builder/content-types/:uid
```

To use the API you must have permissions enabled for a role under `Roles & Permissions`

[Endpoints docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#endpoints)

---

At the time of this update Strapi added a [caution](https://docs.strapi.io/user-docs/latest/content-types-builder/managing-content-types.html#deleting-content-types) (Feb 2022):

> Deleting a content-type only deletes what was created and available from the Content-type Builder ... All the data ... is however kept in the database.

Comment: This is not working for me and reported the issue https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/18799. It does delete the files under src/api and thats all it does. I build reload strapi and no changes

Comment: Issue was moved by Strapi team to "Support" team. lmk

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the server with `npm run develop` or `yarn run develop`

If you started the server with `npm run start` or `yarn run start` you will not see these options.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to skip the tour... It prevents you from deleting anything until it's completed...

Comment: What is the tour?

Comment: @KristiJorgji At the time, it was basically like the "tutorial mode", I think.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by deleting the /dist folder and running "npm run development" again.